# How to copy the contents of a folder to multiple folders based on number of files?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to copy the files from a folder (named: 1) to multiple folders based on the number of files (here: 50).

The code given below works. I transferred all the files from the folder to the subfolders based on number of files and then copied back all the files in the directory back to the initial folder. 
However, I need something cleaner and more efficient. Apologies for the mess below, I'm a nube.

```
bf=1 #breakfolder
cd 1 #the folder from where I wanna copy stuff, contains 179 files

flies_exist=$(ls -1q * | wc -l) #assign the number of files in folder 1

#move 50 files from 1 to various subfolders

while [ $flies_exist -gt 50 ]
do

mkdir ../CompiledPdfOutput/temp/1-$bf
set --
for f in .* *; do
  [ "$#" -lt 50 ] || break
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue
  [ -L "$f" ] && continue
  set -- "$@" "$f"
done

mv -- "$@" ../CompiledPdfOutput/temp/1-$bf/
flies_exist=$(ls -1q * | wc -l)
bf=$(($bf + 1))
done

#mover the rest of the files into one final subdir

mkdir ../CompiledPdfOutput/temp/1-$bf
set --
for f in .* *; do
  [ "$#" -lt 50 ] || break
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue
  [ -L "$f" ] && continue
  set -- "$@" "$f"
done
mv -- "$@" ../CompiledPdfOutput/temp/1-$bf/
#get out of 1
cd ..

# copy back the contents from subdir to 1
find CompiledPdfOutput/temp/ -exec cp {} 1 \;
```

The required directory structure is:

```
        parent
  ________|________
  |               |
  1       CompiledPdfOutput
  |               |
(179)           temp
                  |
             ---------------
             |    |    |    |
            1-1  1-2  1-3  1-4
            (50) (50) (50) (29)
```

The number inside "()" denotes the number of files.

BTW, the final step of my code gives this warning, would be glad if anyone can explain what's happening and a solution.

```
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'CompiledPdfOutput/temp/'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'CompiledPdfOutput/temp/1-4'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'CompiledPdfOutput/temp/1-3'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'CompiledPdfOutput/temp/1-1'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'CompiledPdfOutput/temp/1-2'
```

I dont wnt to copy the directory as well, just the files so giving  -r would be bad.

Comment: Try changing your `find` cmd to include `-type f`. Otherwise, if this is giving the results you need, mark it "case closed". Or at least put improvement of this to the back-burner. Better to spend your time on other code that can make your process or other tasks easier and more efficient. A reasonable (and good) bit of code AND an excellent question, given how often similar poorly writtien questions of this nature appear here. Keep posting and Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I find a couple of issues with the posted script:

- The logic of copying maximum 50 files per folder is overcomplicated, and the code duplication of an entire loop is error-prone.
- It uses reuses the `$@` array of positional parameters for internal storage purposes. This variable was not intended for that, it would be better to use a new dedicated array.
- Instead of moving files to sub-directories and then copying them back, it would be simpler to just copy them in the first step, without ever moving.
- Parsing the output of `ls` is not recommended.

Consider this alternative, simpler logic:

- Initialize an empty array `to_copy`, to keep files that should be copied
- Initialize a folder counter, to use to compute the target folder
- Loop over the source files

  - Apply filters as before (skip if not file)
  - Add file to `to_copy`
  - If `to_copy` contains the target number of files, then:
  - Create the target folder
  - Copy the files contained in `to_copy`
  - Reset the content of `to_copy` to empty
  - Increment `folder_counter`
- If `to_copy` is not empty

  - Create the target folder
  - Copy the files contained in `to_copy`

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

distribute_to_folders() {
    local src=$1
    local target=$2
    local max_files=$3

    local to_copy=()
    local folder_counter=1

    for file in "$src"/* "$src/.*"; do
        [ -f "$file" ] || continue

        to_copy+=("$file")
        if (( ${#to_copy[@]} == max_files )); then
            mkdir -p "$target/$folder_counter"
            cp -v "${to_copy[@]}" "$target/$folder_counter/"
            to_copy=()
            ((++folder_counter))
        fi
    done

    if (( ${#to_copy[@]} > 0 )); then
        mkdir -p "$target/$folder_counter"
        cp -v "${to_copy[@]}" "$target/$folder_counter/"
    fi
}

distribute_to_folders "$@"
```

To distribute files in `path/to/1` into directories of maximum 50 files under `path/to/compiled-output`, you can call this script with:

```
./distribute.sh path/to/1 path/to/compiled-output 50
```

---

> BTW, the final step of my code gives this warning, would be glad if anyone can explain what's happening and a solution.

Sure. The command `find CompiledPdfOutput/temp/ -exec cp {} 1 \;` finds files and directories, and tries to copy them. When `cp` encounters a directory and the `-r` parameter is not specified, it issues the warning you saw. You could add a filter for files, with `-type f`. If there are not excessively many files then a simple shell glob will do the job:

```
cp -v CompiledPdfOutput/temp/*/* 1
```

Comment: <mv -v CompiledPdfOutput/temp/*/* 1> This worked, thanks for that. However , as I mentioned in the question, I wanted to copy the contents and not move it, is there any way to copy the entire thing at once and not copy the contents to the subfolders and copy them back again to the main folder?

Comment: @Arsalan oops! don't know why I wrote `mv`, it should have been `cp`, corrected it now. In fact, you can replace all the `mv` above with `cp` if you want to copy files and not move them.

Comment: @Arsalan I updated my answer to avoid the unnecessary `mv` step at the end. Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you need something more compact/efficient, you can leverage existing tools (find, xargs) to create a pipeline, eliminating the need to program each step using bash.

The following will move the files into the split folder. It will find the files, group them, 50 into each folder, use awk to generate output folder, and move the files. Solution not as elegant as original one :-(

```
find 1 -type f |
    xargs -L50 echo |
    awk '{ print "CompliedOutput/temp/1-" NR, $0 }' |
    xargs -L1 echo mv -t
```

As a side note, current script moves the files from the '1' folder, to the numbered folders, and then copy the file back to the original folder. Why not just copy the files to the numbered folders. You can use 'cp -p' to to preserve timestamp, if that's needed.

**Supporting file names with new lines (and spaces)**

Clarification to question indicate a solution should work with file names with embedded new lines (and while spaces). This require minor change to use NUL character as separator.

```
  # Count number of output folders
DIR_COUNT=$(find 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} echo X | wc -l)
  # Remove previous tree, and create folder
OUT=CompiledOutput/temp
rm -rf $OUT
eval mkdir -p $OUT/1-{1..$DIR_COUNT}

# Process file, use NUL as separator
find 1 -type f -print0 | 
   awk -vRS="\0"  -v"OUT=$OUT" 'NR%50 == 1 { printf "%s/1-%d%s",OUT,1+int(NR/50),RS } { printf "%s", ($0 RS) }' |
   xargs -0 -L51 -t mv -t
```

Did limited testing with both space and new lines in the file. Looks OK on my machine.

Comment: If you need to handle files with spaces/new lines, I believe that you want something "stronger" than awk (python or Perl) to do the formatting. Alternatively you can use escapes to hide the white spaces during processing.

Comment: That would have been my first choice however it's a constraint I have to work with. The code didn't work, all it did was create 179 folders in  OUT <1-1,1-2,1-3....1-179>

Comment: Can you add to the question: (1) runtime environemtn: Window/Linux version (2) names of few files that contain new line/special characters. Mayy be it will be possible to replicate the problem you experience.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy files to multiple folders of fixed size. Change source, target, and folderSize as per your requirement. This also works with filenames with special character (e.g. `'file 131!@#$%^&*()_+-=;?'`).

```
source=1
target=CompiledPDFOutput/temp 
folderSize=50

find $source -type f -printf "\"%p\"\0" \
| xargs -0 -L$folderSize \
| awk '{system("mkdir -p '$target'/1-" NR); printf "'$target'/1-" NR " %s\n", $0}' \
| xargs -L1 cp -t
```

Comment: First, I need to work from inside the dir, so using parent would be a big no-no. Second, it doesn't work with special characters. Third, the contents should be pasted inside the subfolders of temp. Fourth,the editing on @dash-o doesn't works, here's the error <./test.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `|'><./test.sh: line 10: `| xargs -L50 echo '>

Comment: @Arsalan I have updated my solution. This will work with special characters and will copy files to subfolders of temp.